# Load a Webpage and submit the form present on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, automation

I am trying to load a webpage in jquery e.g gmail.com (can be any other site also) , and once the page is loaded i want to fill the username and password and want to click on submit button   .

Once i reached to the inbox page , I want to delete all the spam messages with my jquery code.

Is it possible to do that or any API is available  to do the same.

I tried loading the url in the iframe but after that i was not able to set the values in text fields.

I also looked at the [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html) , but didn't get much out of it.

I am just a novice to jquery and trying to learn it.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Browser security will ensure that you can't do this with jQuery.

Comment: Can we do this with Java or using any other technology ?

Comment: I have used phantomjs in my web automation stuff. So you can go with that. What problem did you faced using phantomjs

Comment: @Mritunjay u did the same thing as i intend to do ? i was going thru their examples but was not sure from where to start.

Comment: @Saurav not same thing but i've done automation in different things.
[Here](https://github.com/mkdskd/phantomjs-automation) is my Github link which has those stuff.

I'll try for your problem also.

Comment: thanks Mritunjay , i will look into your examples and try to make it work.

Comment: And you should also refer phantomjs Docs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56472/discussion-between-mritunjay-and-saurav).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this with jQuery? If you're looking to programmatically make network requests, use a server-side language.

You may be interested in this: https://developers.google.com/gmail/ if you're trying to manipulate gmail programmatically.

What you're doing sounds a lot like spammer, cracker practices, however.

Look up curl, and learn how to make network requests from the command line or from a scripting language such as ruby, python, etc.

Comment: I just thought integrating Ajax with jQuery will be much easier. Gmail is just an example that i have used. My only intention is to automate the repetitive tasks programmatically.

Comment: it's about choosing the right tool for the job. Since you didn't exactly say what your job is it's hard to choose the right tool.but from the sounds of things it seems like jQuery is not the right tool for the job at hand.

Comment: Ok , so which is the right tool and any reference that you would like to suggest.

Comment: "SINCE YOU DIDN'T EXACTLY SAY WHAT YOUR JOB IS IT'S HARD TO CHOOSE THE RIGHT TOOL."

Comment: i.e. please explain exactly what you're trying to do.